# What is a 'control function' in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
control operator
              A token that performs a control function.  It is one of the following symbols:
              || & && ; ;; ( ) | |& <newline>
```

Is this flow control - each one of those tokens will affectthe flow of a program - but newline? And |& and | don't really affect flow.. Could someone explain this to me.

Comment: I guess you are quoting from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html

Comment: All of those tokens affect how processes and their I/O are managed in the shell. For example, execution sequence, foreground/background execution, routing of inputs and outputs to and from other processes (pipes) or to a file handle (screen, etc). A <newline> falls in this category because that's what causes the shell to act. You can type all you want, but until you press <newline>, not much happens. :) Have you used them before?

Comment: hi, standard definition of a function is taken from math - a one-to-one mapping between a domain and a range.. or one input: one and only one output. I'm guessing control functions affect 'flow' rather than like sin(theta) are evaluated solely for their result. ;; will prevent flow from passing to the lower block. && || ! affect flow (logical operators), () - grouping but | and |& just diddle the i/o..

Comment: @paleywiener You're quoting "control operator" from the manual, but then you ask what a "control function" is. Are those two necessarily the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token definitions:

- `||` ("[or](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29)") and `&&` ("[and](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29)") separate two commands, resulting in the second command being executed if the first fail (i.e., returns with non-zero exit code) or succeeds (returns with zero exit code), respectively.
- `;`, newline and `&` ("[background](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_run_a_job_in_the_background.3F)") separate two commands. The first is useful if you want to put "unrelated" commands on the same line. The last also sends a command to the background, continuing execution without waiting for the command to finish.
- `;;` separates two [`case`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29) statements.
- `(` and `)` enclose a set of commands which are run in a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell).
- `|` ("[pipe](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes)") separates two commands, pointing standard output of the first command to standard input of the second command.
- `|&` ("[error pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)") separates two commands, pointing standard output *and* standard error of the first command to standard input of the second command. Try `(echo out; echo err >&2) 2>/dev/null |& cat`

As we can see, newline affects the "flow" of the code by delimiting commands. [*Flow control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29) is defined as follows:

> In data communications, flow control is the process of managing the rate of data transmission between two nodes to prevent a fast sender from overwhelming a slow receiver.

Pipes could be seen as flow control, since standard output (and other file descriptors, if redirected) of the sender will be blocked until the receiver has consumed from standard input.

Comment: hi, the answer while informative doesn't really answer the question of how flow is altered or why they are 'control functions'. I know about 'short circuiting' of AND and OR - all the above stuff is part of the man page - not that I don't appreciate the time and energy you put into drafting your answer, but I can't mark it so if you could append to it and clarify matters - then I could.